# virtual pbx using x-lite stuck at offline

Tags: windows-7, voip, xlite

I am using x-lite to connect to virtualpbx.net. One of my user's x-lite is stuck at offline and the availability dropdown box is grayed out. I don't see any error messages in x-lite or virtualpbx.net. He can still make outgoing calls.

I didn't setup this system and don't know much about VOIP phones, etc. Everytime I google x-lite or virtualpbx i get sales pages. I've looked at https://support.counterpath.com/ but don't see anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In X-lite
2. Softphone -> Account Settings
3. Under "Allow this account for"
4. Check "IM / Presence"

I can't believe this took me so long to figure out but I also can't believe I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere.